# How to create tags using WordPress Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am to creating Posts for my Wordpress site using Wordpress rest API, When i try to post with tags i get an error.

Is it possible to create a post with tags and categories in one call? or i need to first create the post and then after update it for the right tags, categories.

Here is my code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"title":"Example Post By Dev","content":"This zzzz is an example post created using the REST API.","status":"publish","tags":[{"name":"hello"},{"name":"world"}]});

var config = {
method: 'post',
url: 'http://00.000.000.00/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
headers: { 
'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxx=', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
```

Every time i add the 'tags' property i get an error, what am i missing?

Comment: According to [these docs](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/), the `tags` parameter should be a "Comma-separated list or array of tags (name or id)", how did you come up with the `{"name": "..."}` structure?

Comment: yeah u right about the format, but i cant create new tags on the create post call, so i must do it in 3 calls? call 1 create post, call 2 create tag, call 3 update the post with the tags, right?

Comment: I'd say you can do it in two, just create the tag first and then create the post with the created tag id or name. But probably you are right, I am not sure.